# Replace only duplicates and skip unique

Tags: mysql, replace, duplicates, unique, skip

I have this simple table:
(ID is unique key)

```
-----------------------------
-   ID   ----    NAME    ----
-----------------------------
-   1    ----    Peter   ----
-   2    ----   Suzanne  ----
-   3    ----   Thomas   ----
-----------------------------
```

and I want to insert these table data into table using query:

```
-----------------------------
-   ID   ----    NAME    ----
-----------------------------
-   2    ----    Alex    ----
-   4    ----    Eric    ----
-   5    ----    Paul    ----
-----------------------------
```

and what I want is, that data from new table will replace old data and entries, which don't exist in old table get skipped.

So final table will look like this:

```
-----------------------------
-   ID   ----    NAME    ----
-----------------------------
-   1    ----    Peter   ----
-   2    ----    Alex    ----
-   3    ----   Thomas   ----
-----------------------------
```

only line with ID 2 got replaced, lines with IDs 4,5 got skipped, because didn't exist in old table.

Is that possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want an `update`:

```
update table1 t1 join
       table2 t2
       on t1.id = t2.id
    set t1.name = t2.name;
```

Comment: you always beat me to the answer :)